# What's a good starting point for (re)learning the D&D 4e rules?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'd like to program some bots to assist in running D&D 4e games, but I've forgotten all of my 4e rules.

Where would be the best place to relearn the Dungeons & Dragons 4e rules, specifically from the perspective of being a dungeon master?

Comment: I've heavily edited your question, as the extensive background and detail about the bots isn't really necessary for us understanding your situation. I've also rephrased the end sentence from "about being a dungeon master" to "from the perspective of a dungeon master", as the rules _about_ being a dungeon master are near to nonexistent - there's just rules, and the DM leverages them in certain ways.

Comment: Aside, if you want to simulate a roleplaying game with IRC bots, you may want to instead avoid reinvention of large parts of the wheel and look into using the programming facilities built into [MUD servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) — simulating D&D programmatically is what they were created for.

Answer (score 4):

A good starting point would probably be getting your hands on the [Rules Compendium](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7976230-rules-compendium), which contains all the rules of the game.

After that, an [Insider Account](http://dnd.wizards.com/digital_tools) would be a good idea. This gives you access to the Compendium, which gives you the stats (but not the imagery or the full background) of *everything ever published* for 4th Edition. It's a wealth of technical information for making adventures.

Unfortunately the last question isn't as easy to answer. Learning to be a Dungeon Master is more of an art than a science, and even for people can take years to become really good at. Transferring that skill to a computer program is next to impossible. If you want inspiration, check out how existing games in the D&D genre do it. Since you're looking at an IRC-bot, you probably want to go *way back* and check out old text-adventure style games.